# Calling a function remotely setting EAX and ECX

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, memory, reverse-engineering

Im trying to start a function resident in another program in runtime and remotely.

Using ollydbg i got the function address and im using [CreateRemoteThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx) to start this function, it actually runs this function but, it recives two arguments and without those arguments the program crash.

The problem is that this fuction get arguments/parameters from EAX and ECX that are pushed to this function before it's called (those two values are both matrix coordenates that goes from 1 to 576~~)

[image: Function its called at 10038B1 and recives ECX and EAX]

[Createremotethread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx) didn't worked for inseting parameters, i tried using struct to use multiple (2) arguments but the values from the registers don't change.

**How can i make this fuction run on the other program by being started from an another distinct program and setting those two registers?**

this is the code where i call the thread to execute this function in 0x01003084

```
    struct tagRemoteThreadParams //didnt worked
    {
        int Param1;
        int Param2;
    } RemoteThreadParams, *PRemoteThreadParams;


    RemoteThreadParams.Param1 = 0x00000001;//didnt worked
    RemoteThreadParams.Param2 = 0x00000001;//didnt worked


    int address=0x010038B1; // 0x01003084   --  0x01002FE0 -- 0x01003512  //Some addresses

    RedrawWindow(Find,NULL,NULL,RDW_ERASE|RDW_INVALIDATE|RDW_INTERNALPAINT|RDW_FRAME); //my program stuff

    DWORD rc;

    //this is where i call the function
    CreateRemoteThread(hProcess,NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)address,&RemoteThreadParams,0,&rc);

    rc = WaitForSingleObject( hProcess, 30000 ); 
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)address, 0, MEM_RELEASE | MEM_DECOMMIT);
```

Have in mind that i don't want to use DLL injection (this is not what im searching for), i actually want to make this just with one code.
Thanks.

Comment: Dealing with registers directly is OS/target specific?? Did you miss to specify tags for narrowing?

Comment: This is in Windows, IA32

Comment: Many compilers allow embedding assembly instructions in C/C++ code, but syntax varies greatly between different compilers.  What compiler are you using?  Have you already read the docs?

Comment: CreateRemoteThread only allows you to invoke functions accepting a single LPVOID parameter (like ThreadProc). Considering the fact that you're freeing the page containing the function: are you injecting this function yourself? If so: change the signature so it conforms to ThreadProc. If not: perhaps you can inject a helper function first (with ThreadProc's signature) that pushes the members of your struct (passed as LPVOID) onto the stack before calling your actual target.

Comment: @Paulo1205 im using g++, yes, the registers that i want to change are the other program, not the one that im writing, so writing in asm would only affect it if i inject the code on the other program

Comment: @heinrichj how do a function that recives LPVOID looks is asm? I thought of using a helper function, but i don't want to use Dlls, and if i try to use WriteProcessMemory i would have to translate the function to OP codes and i actually don't know how to, and this new injected code would have to revice 2 values from a thread too.

Comment: @Ollegn You can't readily tell the signature from the assembly of a function. If your two parameter values are known to you at injection time you could just hardcode them: just inject a piece of code with two push instructions pushing constants followed by a call-instruction to the target function. You can use something like WinASM to encode these assembly instructions; you'll just need to replace the variable (non-instruction) bytes.

Comment: @heinrichj i really don't want to change the target asm, i could just make a code cave and put some code that does this for me, but later i want to distribute just the main code, so ppl can use this code without having to make this code cave in the target.

Answer (score 1):

Your only solution really is to inject code into the other process that does the right setup of the registers, and then calling the function you want to call. The `CreateRemoteThread` has strict calling convention, so you can't force it to have specific register values on entry.

The other alternative is to use the [debug functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows to alter the register content, but this requires that you  stop the code [in the correct thread] at the right place and set the registers before continuing. Which is tricky and most applications (assuming we're taliing games etc) have protection to prevent debug functions from "messing" with their state.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot pass that function as the thread proc for `CreateRemoteThread` because that function does not have the correct signature. So, you need to pass a function that does have the right signature.

One very common way to do that is to pass the address of `LoadLibrary`. You'll need to supply your own DLL. The `DllMain` for that DLL can then create a new thread that calls your function.

But you say that you don't want to involve another DLL. So to my mind that leaves one option. Allocate some memory in the virtual address space of the target process. Make that memory have executable protection. Write into that memory a thread procedure with the correct signature for `CreateRemoteThread`. And inside this thread procedure, finally, call the desired function.